# User secrets null in build

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm making an asp.net core application and using user secrets. User secrets are set properly and I can see them when I right click the project -> Manage user secrets. Everything works fine inside Visual Studio when I hit "Debug". But when I build my app and launch the .dll file, it is not retrieving the user secret properly and is getting an empty string from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building the app and deploying it, the secret manager will not work. The Secret Manager tool for development purposes only. The Secret Manager tool doesn't encrypt the stored secrets and shouldn't be treated as a trusted store. The keys and values are stored in a JSON configuration file in the user profile directory. More details on [Safe storage of app secrets in development in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=windows&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040). If you're deploying to Azure use [Azure Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-portal?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002040) or [Azure App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002040) for managing secrets.